# DynamoDB ConditionalCheckFailedException - obtaining the item content that failed the test

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-net

I'm using precondition expressions on `PutItem` and `UpdateItem` requests.

Is there a way to achieve either or both of the following:

1. not throw an exception - this is not an exceptional situation, it's an anticipated condition; as with validation of external inputs, I would like to be able to inspect the result without there being a throw and a catch - is there a way to achieve that?
2. given the server has just read the data in order to determine the check failed, is it possible to have it return it, given the RCUs have already been paid and the general pattern is that the before/after can be included as part of the roundtrip? Or is this a truly hard-baked service-side limitation? Would love to see a link to something authoritative as any docs I've traversed are silent on the matter...

(I'm using a current version of the .NET SDK `AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2` NuGet package.)

Comment: Can you try adding a `ReturnValues` for the requests of value `ALL_NEW`? Intellisense should help you figure out the specifics. See if that returns the values? If not, try `ALL_OLD` too. Also - what is the problem with exceptions? You can abstract it away - what is the actual problem? SDK client design or do you need no exceptions for a very specific reason? Can you please add some code where the exception is being thrown?

Comment: You get an exception instead of a result from the core call. [I am requesting the return values](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.AWS.DynamoDB/blob/0914a3af9e348dbc5412fc3859fab7849c1d75f5/src/FSharp.AWS.DynamoDB/TableContext.fs#L345) - [the calling code](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/ddb/src/Equinox.DynamoStore/DynamoStore.fs#L418-L422) has no choice but to do a try/catch. IMO Exceptions are inefficient an inappropriate as a way of modelling an expected failure - similar to how you dont typically throw in input validation logic

Comment: I agree with you, exceptions should be more of a Java thing - try contacting AWS support or log something on the forums. However, unless you decide to call the endpoint yourself and create a mini client, you won't be able to go around the exception. I would just handle it in your `AwsAdapter`

Comment: I have no choice but to handle the egregious exception, but the most important bit is definitely to avoid the extra roundtrip. Before anything happens the first thing to understand is whether the server can or will be in a position to return the state in the case of a precondition check or not. Hopefully an answer will arrive here in due course without me having do retraverse it all in a forum ;)

Comment: Unfortunately no, the API does not return any more information. This is an AWS limitation, not an SDK one.

Answer (score 6):

[Since Jun 30, 2023](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/06/amazon-dynamodb-cost-failed-conditional-writes/), DynamoDB supports a [ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure) parameter that returns a copy of the item as it was during the write attempt at no additional cost within the `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

Therefore, the desired behavior is possible nowadays.

Comment: Oh thank you - accept incoming when I've validated it works. Now to find out when the local DDB simulator does it too!

Answer (score 1):

You can see the low-level wire activity documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html which show a 400 response status code if the conditional check fails. At this time there’s no more knowledge to be gained on the failed call without a second call.

Comment: +1 but I had seen and tried to consider what that page says but tats exactly what I was referring to when I said the docs where silent on the matter -- I think its a stretch to say that it documents the low level wire activity or delves into the intent - there are def lots of bits of circumstantial evidence like the exception being thrown etc, but for me there's also nothing saying a 400 cant return a body etc

Comment: If it returned a body it would say so. You can also try yourself if you’re inclined.

Comment: (This all seems to check out. See also other answer - `TransactWriteItems` has `ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure` properties in its `Request` structures, which cause inclusion of said items in the `TransactionCanceledException` - note that the request charges are twice the typical ones, so that's is definitely not a universal and/or obvious 'solution' to the overall question/need I had in porting logic which happened to work elegantly in CosmosDB...)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've just found (but no yet tested) the answer... The Put (and Update) operation in  [`TransactWriteItems`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html) has a `ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure`. <strike>Unless there is a truly major overhead to that, that's my answer...</strike>

---

Looks like the way you extract the item is still sadly by extracting it out of the exception in this sort of manner:

```
try let! response = client.TransactWriteItemsAsync(req, ct) |> Async.AwaitTaskCorrect
with :? TransactionCanceledException as e -> e.CancellationReasons.[0].Item
```

The other key difference between a `TransactWriteItems` vs single `PutItem` / `UpdateItem` calls are that you can't obtain the (original or) updated item in the success case.

---

I've yet to validate this works correctly end to end at the present time - the key shortcoming is that [the Request Charge Units levied for `TransactWriteItems` are twice that incurred for individual `PutItem`/`UpdateItem`/`DeleteItem` requests](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-transactions/). Thus while for transactional correctness being able to extract the conflicting item may be useful, it's definitely not applicable as a general technique unless you happen to require the atomicity.

Excellent [costing guide article](https://zaccharles.medium.com/calculating-a-dynamodb-items-size-and-consumed-capacity-d1728942eb7c).